# Google AdMob banner event integration in SwiftUI

Tags: admob, integration, swiftui

I have a ad banner integrate in swiftUI with UIViewControllerRepresentable but i doesn't know to add event like adViewDidReceiveAd(). I have learn on https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit but the event adViewDidReceiveAd never start

```
   struct GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

func makeCoordinator() -> GADBannerViewController.Coordinator {
    GADBannerViewController.Coordinator()
   }

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let view = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    view.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    view.rootViewController = viewController
    viewController.view.addSubview(view)
    viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: kGADAdSizeBanner.size)
    view.load(GADRequest())
    return viewController
}


func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}


class Coordinator: NSObject, GADBannerViewDelegate {
   func  adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView){
    print("AAAAAAAAA")
    }

   func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
            print(error)
        }


}

}
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58364819/1971013) and let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi, i have "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" error for the line "Coordinator(self)"

Comment: and Type 'GADBannerViewController.Coordinator' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol' for the class coordinator

Comment: Please check you've missed anything shown here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit  If you still have issues post the code, because error messages without seeing code are hard to understand.

Comment: i re update my question @meaning-matters

Comment: At the moment I don't see any question. What do you mean with "the event not launch"?

Comment: I mean the function adViewDidReceiveAd never start, like in https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner#implementing_banner_events or in this Kilo Loco video : https://youtu.be/TMj_3mQA39g?t=1052

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds    

final class GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable  {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        view.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735713"
        view.rootViewController = viewController
        view.delegate = viewController
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: kGADAdSizeBanner.size)
        view.load(GADRequest())
        return viewController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}

extension UIViewController: GADBannerViewDelegate {
    public func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("ok ad")
    }

    public func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
       print("fail ad")
       print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is GADBannerViewController a class? It should be a struct. You're adding overhead for 0 utility.

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution, I post here for others :

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds


final class GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable  {


    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        let viewController = UIViewController()
        view.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735713"
        view.rootViewController = viewController
        view.delegate = viewController
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: kGADAdSizeBanner.size)
        view.load(GADRequest())

        return viewController
    }


    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}

}







extension UIViewController: GADBannerViewDelegate {
    public func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("ok ad")
    }

    public func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("fail ad")
        print(error)
    }
}
```